# RepositoryRestController: POST with multiple HAL URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I've `OneToMany` relation between `User` & `Address` and `ManyToOne` relation with `EmploymentType`.

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    //..
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private EmploymentType employmentType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<>();
    //..
}

@Entity
public class Skill {
    //..
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    //..
}

@Entity
public class EmploymentType {
    //..
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    //..
}

@RepositoryRestController
public class CustomUserController {
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @PostMapping(path = "/users/createUserWithEmploymentType")
    public @ResponseBody String  createUserWithEmploymentType(@RequestBody EntityModel<User> users) {
        System.out.println(users);
        // ....
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

        @PostMapping(path = "/users/createUserWithSkillBatch")
    public @ResponseBody String createUserWithSkill(@RequestBody CollectionModel<EntityModel<User>> users) {
        System.out.println(users);
        // ....
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

I need to use custom `RepositoryRestController` for some additional check before I persist the records.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name": "Kiran Kyle", "employmentType": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employmentTypes/1"}' http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/createUserWithEmploymentType
```

This curl works.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '[{"name": "Kiran Kyle", "skill": ["http://localhost:8080/api/v1/skills/1", "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/skills/2"]}]' http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/createUserWithSkillBatch
```

This does not giving error `...ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type` org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel`from Array value (token`JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type` org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel`from Array value (token`JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]`

It seems when there is an array of HAL URI's, spring does not convert to entity object.

Comment: You should not use `CollectionModel` or `EntityModel` as request body type.

Comment: @yejianfengblue if CollectionModel or EntityModel is not used resource uri's are not resolved to entities and we get JSON parse error. That was my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used RequestBody as CollectionModel, you might have to send array of objects instead of single object to CURL command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '[{"name": "Kiran Kyle", "skill": ["http://localhost:8080/api/v1/skills/1", "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/skills/2"]}]' http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/createUserWithSkill
```

Comment: Gopinath Radhakrishana, it does not work. I updated CollectionModel<EntityModel<User>>> to CollectionModel<User>. It does not give me parsing error but get blank user now. Here is the application. https://github.com/roykyle8/repositoryrestcontroller